# Why doesn't the animtor animate in unity5?

Tags: unity, animation

I have a player consisting of 20 different body parts which I have animated into a walking cycle. When I play the animation in an 'animation' component it works as intended, but when I try to play it from an animator nothing happens.
[image]

The player is animated when the animation component is checked.

It does not animate when only the animator component is checked.

[image]

It is however running the animation, yet nothing happens in the scene.
I have no scripts attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey can you check the animation type for the clip. Make sure it is not legacy while using it with mecanim. Make the animation clip mode to loop (helps while testing). 
Also click on Walking_test and check the inspector if the anim clip is assigned properly. If you already have checked for these things then while playing with mecanim try removing the animation component instead of just disabling it. It will be great if you can provide more information about the animation clip.

Comment: I had to use debug mode to turn legacy off, but once I did, and reimported the clip into the animator, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Yes that's the only way to change the type , too bad its not directly accessible to the user :(